# An alternative to friend when overloading >>?

Tags: c++, overloading, friend, functor

In the situation below, is there any alternative to using friend? I would like to preserve all functionality of overloading the operator >>. I do not want to have public accessors in the reader class.

```
struct FunctorBase
{
    virtual ~FunctorBase(){}
    virtual void operator()(Reader &reader) const = 0;
};

//does specific stuff related to the purpose of end.
struct end : FunctorBase
{
    void operator()(Reader &reader) const
    {
        //work with private data in reader
    }
};

class Reader
{
    friend class end; //I want to get rid of this if possible without losing the
                      //functionality of operator>> or providing accessors

    Reader& operator>>(const FunctorBase &functor)
    {
        functor(*this);

        return *this;
    }
};
```

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I plan on having multiple derived classes of FunctorBase, thus multiple friend declarations. Isn't this abusing the concept of friend?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the best solution depends on what **end** has to do with **Reader**.

Did you think about a base class with private inheritance (kind of interface)? You'll expose only what you need and it won't be accesible to others. Just as example:

```
class ReaderInterface
{
public:
    void method()
    {
    }
};

// This is your "end" class, derived from FunctorBase,
// the consumer of ReaderInterface
class Consumer
{
public:
    Consumer(ReaderInterface readerInterface)
    {
        readerInterface.method();
    }
};

class Reader : private ReaderInterface
{
public:
    void test()
    {
        Consumer consumer(*this);
    }
};
```

Comment: I've always been taught that private inheritance is wrong - but in this case it isn't any different than a friend declaration.  Even if I used function pointers instead of structs with operator() overload, they would still have to be declared friend anyways such as when working with iostream. So I think I will just stick with the friend declaration.

Comment: They are both "implementation details" of your class but I agree that private inheritance is not common and shouldn't be abused. At least you can decide **what you want to make visible**, a friend sees **everything**.

Comment: Very true. As another alternative, I could define an operator>> overload for each struct, but that ruins the beauty of the polymorphism and inheritance being used.